# Magnetic Force Between 3 parallel conductors

Tags: current, electromagnetism, wire, electromagnetic, conductors

I have a problem with 3 parallel conductors carrying currents, as shown in the picture. I need to determine the force per meter length acting on the bottom-right conductor (carrying current I2).

[image]

I know that I have to use these formulas. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: @periblepsis
I do have insights on the matter. I know that you have to first calculate B1 and B3 and you add them together to get B13, after that you calculate F2 (final result). But I don't know how to calculate B1, B3, F2.

Comment: Each current projects a \$\vec{B}\$ onto the other two wires (never on itself, of course, as a current on a wire cannot self-propel.) You should be able to draw the direction and calculate the magnitude of each onto your diagram. There will be six of these, two on each wire going into and out of the paper sheet there. Do you think you should then sum these vector pairs at each wire before computing the force per meter?

Comment: Would you agree with the following [force vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9bwr.png)?